# Find the actual DbSet for CRUD actions dynamically

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have searched on this site and am having trouble getting the actual DbSet from my context. I am trying to retrieve each dbset dynamically based on tablename.

```
 var dynamicdbset = GetDbSetByTableName(uploadTableName); //Dbset name is Mytables


  private dynamic GetDbSetByTableName(string tableName)
        {
            MyEntities context = new MyEntities();
            System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(ClearGUIEntities).GetProperties();
            var prop = properties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == tableName + "s");

            using (var db = new MyEntities())
            {
                var dbset = prop?.GetValue(db);
                return dbset;
            }

        }
```

The issue here is it is returning some generic dbset but I can't use linq nor can I do a simple operation like

```
dynamicdbset.Where(t = > t.Id == 123).Single();
```

I need to be able to get the dbset dynamically by tablename and also query the data the same way I would be able to do if I create it specifically like

```
var value = context.MyTables.FirstorDefault()
```

Comment: If you just load a dbSet without materializing it into a specific type, how can you (or .net) know that there even is a `.Id` property on it? That's why you can't use Linq on it. It's pretty rare that you would truly need to load data like this, it's probably a symptom of something else, but if you do, you could look at casting it to some sort of base table type, and querying on those properties. Or querying with string (instead of strongly-typed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The returned dynamic `DbSet` is actually just a wrapper around the real `DbSet` object, which you could simply cast to. The problem is, however, the type of the `DbSet` could not be inferred without using a [generic method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods).

The following would work but it is probably least preferable:

```
private IEnumerable<T> GetDbSetByTableName<T>(string tableName)
{
    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(ClearGUIEntities).GetProperties();
    var prop = properties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == tableName + "s");

    using (var db = new ClearGUIEntities())
    {
        var dbset = prop?.GetValue(db);

        return new List<T>(dbset as IEnumerable<T>);
    }
}
```

Now, to work around this, we have at least two options:

1. Create an interface (with all the base properties you need) that is implemented by all the `DbSet`s. This way, we can cast the dynamic object without having to specify a type while converting.
2. Return an `IEnumerable<dynamic>` which can be cast on the fly.

### Option 1

```
public interface IBaseProperties
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyTable : IBaseProperties
{
    // Add these with either T4 templates or create partial class for each of these entities
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

private IEnumerable<IBaseProperties> GetDbSetByTableName(string tableName)
{
    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(ClearGUIEntities).GetProperties();
    var prop = properties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == tableName + "s");

    using (var db = new ClearGUIEntities())
    {
        var dbset = prop?.GetValue(db);

        return new List<IBaseProperties>(dbset as IEnumerable<IBaseProperties>);
    }
}

// ...
// Using it
// ...

var dynamicdbset = GetDbSetByTableName("MyTable");

int id = dynamicdbset.FirstOrDefault().Id;
```

### Option 2

```
private IEnumerable<dynamic> GetDbSetByTableName(string tableName)
{
    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(ClearGUIEntities).GetProperties();
    var prop = properties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == tableName + "s");

    using (var db = new ClearGUIEntities())
    {
        var dbset = prop?.GetValue(db);

        return new List<dynamic>(dbset as IEnumerable<dynamic>);
    }
}

// ...

// At this point, you can basically access any property of this entity
// at the cost of type-safety
string id = dynamicdbset.FirstOrDefault().Id;
string name = dynamicdbset.FirstOrDefault().Name;
```

BTW, the casting to `List<T>` is necessary because you're using the object outside of the `using` block, at which point it would have been disposed.

```
new List<IBaseProperties>(dbset as IEnumerable<IBaseProperties>);
```

Comment: With the first suggested GetDbSetByTableName<T>(string tableName) how would I call it? Im using var dbset = GetDbSetByTableName("mytable") and getting an error The type arguments for method 'GetDbSetByTableName<T>(string)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: Well, the first would be the least preferred actually. But you would use it like `var dbset = GetDbSetByTableName<MyTable>("mytable")`;

Comment: Please consider either Option 1 or 2 instead.

Comment: Yea I went ahead with option 1. It makes more sense

Comment: Actually for some strange reason when i hit this line :var returnvalue =  new List<IBaseProperties>(dbset as IEnumerable<IBaseProperties>); Visual studio hangs. I get no errors nor exceptions it just hangs until I restart. Any idea?

Comment: Assuming you have implemented the properties explicitly, how complex is your entity model? Maybe it's doing some heavy work adding those to list, because doing `new List()` should be the same as doing `dbset.ToList()` which would've worked. Or it could have silently thrown a NullReference exception but was handled by a try-catch block?

Comment: Maybe you can create a custom class implementing `IEnumerable<>` and do the conversion there, since we're already using [pattern matching casting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/safely-cast-using-pattern-matching-is-and-as-operators), and possibly also log them along the way.